# IE8 Socket.IO error?

Tags: socket.io

Error occured in IE 8

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; IPMS/E040400A-14E2CBD58A8-000000501208; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)
Timestamp: Mon, 25 Jul 2011 04:39:36 UTC

lines: 2979
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/sosiman/Desktop/sockets/socket.io.js

This line is "req.open(method || 'GET', this.prepareUrl() + '?t' + (+ new Date));"

WARNING: web-socket-js doesn't work in file:///... URL unless you set Flash Security Settings properly. Open the page via Web server i.e. http://...

It's find works in FF, chrom
But IE8 did't work

Any ideas how to fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are testing it from your local drive, and IE doesn't allow that, so serve that page over a server and the error should disappear